# Why cannot I input arrays as digitalWrite arguments?

Tags: digital

I am making my own "7 segment LED driver". I know there is a lot of examples on the internet, I just want to try my own. But I have a piece of code that does not work and I don't know why. Can somebody explain to me why it is not working?

When I put in this, it works:

```
digitalWrite(pins[0], one[0]);
digitalWrite(pins[1], one[1]);
digitalWrite(pins[2], one[2]);
digitalWrite(pins[3], one[3]);
digitalWrite(pins[4], one[4]);
digitalWrite(pins[5], one[5]);
digitalWrite(pins[6], one[6]);
```

So of course I tried using for():

```
for (byte i = 0; i >= 6; i++)
  {
    digitalWrite(pins[i], one[i]);
  }
```

And this does not work. But why? I think it should. Btw. *pins* is const byte array and *one* is const bool array.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Comment: I don't see why it shouldn't work; what happens instead?

Comment: The seven segment display stays off, nothing lights up; but i am sure i have it connected right, because the first code works. But the compiler doesn't give any errors....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've written the `for` loop incorrectly.

```
for (byte i = 0; i >= 6; i++)   <-- ERROR HERE
  {
    digitalWrite(pins[i], one[i]);
  }
```

That first line should be `for (byte i = 0; i <= 6; i++)`. `i` begins at zero, which is less than six, and the loop only runs while `i` is greater than 6.